# DropdownSearch with a controller?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a controller for my selecteditem in dropdownsearch button. Another post says that there is a dropdownsearch controller but i cant find it anywhere. Any assistance?

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
                            dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10)),
                            mode: Mode.MENU,
                            items: [
                              "Test 1",
                              "Test 2",
                              "Test 3",
                            ],
                            onChanged: print,
                            selectedItem: diagnosisDropdown),
```

Comment: could you provide the package name?

Comment: currently its just testpage, im practicing before implementing it to my main code

Comment: on default dropdown button you can access the the dropdown clicked item by `onchanged` listner .here also .why you need control .what you want achieve .could you answer .then i could help you.

Comment: because im using sqflite. i need the controller/option chose from the dropdown button so i can save it.

Comment: do you want to save the selected item from dropdown widget to SQLite?

Comment: yes, with textfields i can use texteditingcontroller but im unsure what i should do for the dropdown widget

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html.you will get changed value in `onchanged` method . you can use that value

Comment: thank you so much, i was just thinking about it way too far and forgot about a simple answer! thanks :D